# Проверить input на length и показать кнопку очистить

Tags: javascript, html, css

На сайте будет много полей, у некоторых будет кнопка, чтоб очистить поле сразу

Пытаюсь, проверить кол-во символов в input

Если кол-во символов больше 1, добавляю класс к кнопке, который скрыть через `css opacity`

Почему-то не добавляется класс

По клику на кнопку **clean**, хочу очистить **input**

```js
let inputWithClear = document.querySelectorAll('.input-clear');
inputWithClear.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
    if (item.value.length > 1) {
      item.nextNode.classList.add('_active');
    } else {
      item.nextNode.classList.remove('_active');
    }
  })
});
let buttonClear = document.querySelectorAll('.button-clean');
buttonClear.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    item.prevNode.value = '';
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="search" class="header__search">
  <button type="button" class="icon-search"></button>
  <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Поиск" class="form-control input-clear" />
  <span class="icon-close button-clean">Х</span>
</div>
```

Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка, что делаю не так?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function updateButtonVisibility(input) {
    const button = input.nextElementSibling;
    if (input.value.length <= 1) {
        button.classList.add('hidden');
    } else {
        button.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
}

function clearField(input) {
    input.value = '';
    updateButtonVisibility(input);
}

const inputWithClear = document.querySelectorAll('.inputWithClear');

inputWithClear.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('input', () => {
        updateButtonVisibility(item);
    });

    const clearButton = item.nextElementSibling;
    clearButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        clearField(item);
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Form 1</h2>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Поиск" class="inputWithClear">
    <button class="clearButton hidden">Очистить</button>
</form>

<h2>Form 2</h2>
<form>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Полное Имя" class="inputWithClear">
        <button class="clearButton hidden">Очистить Полное Имя</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="surName" placeholder="Фамилия" class="inputWithClear">
        <button class="clearButton hidden">Очистить Фамилию</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Этот код позволяет динамически управлять кнопками "Очистить" для полей ввода, и они будут отображаться и скрываться в зависимости от содержимого полей.

Comment: У вас отправляется форма, что не должно быть... Так же нет добавления класса кнопке. И судя по коду, очистка происходит только для первой найденной формы, хотя по условию, их может быть несколько и первая найденная форма, далеко не факт, что нужная

Comment: В описании к коду дополнительно предоставил ссылки GitHub и Github Pages где использовалось больше полей ввода и несколько форм, данные кнопки делают только очистку выбранных полей ввода. Обновил код

Comment: Т.е. если будет 100 полей и форм, вы предлагаете написать 100 дубликатов кода под каждое поле?

Comment: Обновил код, я объединил кнопки "Очистить" в общий класс "clearButton", и для всех полей с классом "inputWithClear" я использую одну и ту же логику. Это делает код более эффективным и удобным для обслуживания, даже если  есть много полей и форм.

Comment: хорошее решение

Answer (score 1):

Во первых по хорошему стоит работать с родительским элементом. Вначале собираем все `div` с классом `input-clear`. Потом для каждого элемента поля ввода мы получаем его внутренние элементы с помощью метода `querySelector` (в нашем случае это button и input) и уже с ними и работаем

Я так же исправил:

`input.value.length > 1` на `input.value.length >= 1` (иначе условие срабатывает только если в поле ввода 2 символа)

и

`addEventListener('keypress')` на `addEventListener('input')`. Первое событие вызывается слишком рано, и значение поля `input.value` просто не успевает обновляться.

**UPDATED:** По просьбе добавил создание кнопки через код

Финальный код:

```js
let inputsWithClear = document.querySelectorAll('.input-clear');
function createButton() {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.type = "button";
    button.classList.add("icon-search");
    return button;
}
inputsWithClear.forEach(item => {
  let input = item.querySelector("input");
  let button = createButton();
  item.insertBefore(button, item.firstChild);
  input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (input.value.length >= 1) {
      button.classList.add('_active');
    } else {
      button.classList.remove('_active');
    }
  })
  
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.value = '';
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="search" class="header__search input-clear">
  <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Поиск" class="form-control" />
  <span class="icon-close button-clean">Х</span>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно кнопку очистить добавить через js? то есть на html не будет кнопка очистить, js проверяет, есть ли класс input-clear, если есть класс, то создает кнопку после input

Comment: @Алесь Конечно можно! отредактировал ответ

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в nextNode и prevNode

Используйте `nextElementSibling` и `previousElementSibling`

```js
let inputWithClear = document.querySelectorAll('.input-clear');
inputWithClear.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
        if (item.value.length > 0) {
            item.nextElementSibling.classList.add('_active');
        } else {
            item.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('_active');
        }
    })
});
let buttonClear = document.querySelectorAll('.button-clean');
buttonClear.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        item.previousElementSibling.value = '';
    })
});
```

```html
<div id="search" class="header__search">
    <button type="button" class="icon-search"></button>
    <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Поиск" class="form-control input-clear" />
    <span class="icon-close button-clean">Х</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Если очистить поле по кнопке, то класс не удаляется. input.value у вас предыдущий в слушателе. И если стирать введенное, слушатель не реагирует

Answer (score 0):

Предложу вариант с использованием классов, для множественного добавления полей с единым поведением

Создадим класс, который будет создавать необходимые элементы, слушатели и нужную логику.

```
class ControlInput {
  #visible = false;
  #input;
  #search;
  #clear;
  #container;
  #searchFn;
  constructor(name, target) {
    this.#searchFn = typeof searchFn === 'function' ? searchFn : (e) => console.log(e);
    this.#container = document.createElement('div');
    // Создаем кнопку поиска
    this.#search = document.createElement('button')
    this.#search.id = `search${name}`;
    this.#search.className = 'btnSearch';
    this.#search.innerText = 'Поиск';
    // Создаем поле ввода
    this.#input = document.createElement('input');
    this.#input.name = name;
    this.#input.addEventListener('input', this.onInput.bind(this));
    // Создаем кнопку очистки значений
    this.#clear = document.createElement('span');
    this.#clear.innerText = 'X';
    this.#clear.className = 'btnSearch';
    this.#clear.addEventListener('click', this.onClear.bind(this));
    // Складываем элементы в контейнер
    this.#container.appendChild(this.#search);
    this.#container.appendChild(this.#input);
    this.#container.appendChild(this.#clear);
    // Добавляем в DOM как дочерний элемент
    document.getElementById(target)?.appendChild(this.#container);
  }

  onInput() {
    if (!this.#visible && this.#input.value.length > 1) {
      this.#visible = true;
      this.#search.classList.add('_active');
    }
    if (this.#input.value.length < 2) {
      this.#visible = false;
      this.#search.classList.remove('_active');
    }
  }

  onClear() {
    this.#search.classList.remove('_active');
    this.#input.value = '';
    this.#visible = false;
  }

  onSearch() {
    this.#searchFn(this.#input.value);
  }

}
```

Класс создаем кнопку поиска, поле ввода и кнопку очистки поля ввода.
Для кнопок назначаются свои обработчики событий нажатия и ввода.

На вход класс принимает имя будущего элемента и ID контейнера, в котором надо разместить нужный блок.

Один раз описав нужную логику, далее добавление добавление новых полей будет сводится к тому, что нужно создать новый экземпляр класса, передав ему имя, контейнер для вставки и функцию поиска.

```
new ControlInput(`field${i}`, 'manyInputs', myFunction);
```

Если заходите управлять ими из JS, то экземпляр можно положить в переменную

```
const myInpyt = new ControlInput(`field${i}`, 'manyInputs');
```

Полный пример кода

```js
const functionRnd = [
  (q) => console.log(`Первый поиск ${q}`),
  (q) => console.log(`И опять ищем ${q}`),
  (q) => console.log(`Давай дублировать ${q}-${q}`),
  null
];

class ControlInput {
  #visible = false;
  #input;
  #search;
  #clear;
  #container;
  #searchFn;
  constructor(name, target, searchFn) {
    this.#searchFn = typeof searchFn === 'function' ? searchFn : (e) => console.log(`По умолчанию ${e}`);
    this.#container = document.createElement('div');
    this.#search = document.createElement('button')
    this.#search.id = `search${name}`;
    this.#search.className = 'btnSearch';
    this.#search.innerText = 'Поиск';
    this.#search.addEventListener('click', this.onSearch.bind(this));

    this.#input = document.createElement('input');
    this.#input.name = name;
    this.#input.addEventListener('input', this.onInput.bind(this));

    this.#clear = document.createElement('span');
    this.#clear.innerText = 'X';
    this.#clear.className = 'btnSearch';
    this.#clear.addEventListener('click', this.onClear.bind(this));

    this.#container.appendChild(this.#search);
    this.#container.appendChild(this.#input);
    this.#container.appendChild(this.#clear);
    document.getElementById(target)?.appendChild(this.#container);
  }

  onInput() {
    if (!this.#visible && this.#input.value.length > 1) {
      this.#visible = true;
      this.#search.classList.add('_active');
      this.#clear.classList.add('_active');
    }
    if (this.#input.value.length < 2) {
      this.#visible = false;
      this.#search.classList.remove('_active');
      this.#clear.classList.remove('_active');
    }
  }

  onClear() {
    this.#search.classList.remove('_active');
    this.#clear.classList.remove('_active');
    this.#input.value = '';
    this.#visible = false;
  }

  onSearch() {
    this.#searchFn(this.#input.value);
  }

}

const fields = 4;
for (let i = 0; i < fields; i++) {
  new ControlInput(`field${i}`, 'manyInputs', functionRnd[i % functionRnd.length] );
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', () => {
  new ControlInput(Math.random().toString(), 'manyInputs', functionRnd[Math.round(Math.random() * 100) % functionRnd.length]);
});
```

```css
.btnSearch {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btnSearch._active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="manyInputs"></div>
<br />
<br />
<button id="add">Хочу еще поле</button>
```